# How to make Android App backward compatible when AIDL interface gets updated

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, aidl

**How to make Android App backward compatible when AIDL interface gets updated?**

For example, if my app accesses an AIDL interface to complete IPC call:

```
interface SampleAidl {
    int sampleMethod(int i);
}
```

On a different platform, the same AIDL updates to a new version which not only changes the arguments of original sampleMethod but also adds another method:

```
interface SampleAidl {
    int sampleMethod(int i, byte[] ext);
    void sampleMethodExtra();
}
```

The AIDL name and packages remain the same.

I have a flag which could decide which version of AIDL to use.
**The question is, if there is any solution/clue that my app could include both versions of AIDL in compile time, and then runtime pick up the right one just by the flag?**

Or the only way is, my app needs to have separate versions to support different AIDLs?

Answer (score 0):

From Android 10 onwards it supports stable Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL), a new way to keep track of the application program interface (API)/application binary interface (ABI) provided by AIDL interfaces. Stable AIDL has the following key differences from AIDL:

- Interfaces are defined in the build system with aidl_interfaces.
- Interfaces can contain only structured data. Parcelables representing the desired types are automatically created based on their AIDL definition and are automatically marshaled and unmarshalled.
- Interfaces can be declared as stable (backward-compatible). When this happens, their API is tracked and versioned in a file next to the AIDL interface.

You can go through here for more details - https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/aidl/stable-aidl#versioning-interfaces

If you are using old simple AIDL then you can update your AIDL interface with this Stable AIDL - https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/aidl/stable-aidl#dealing-with-older-interfaces